# Squash commits based on message

Tags: git

Using a push-to-deploy system in my local development environment generates lots of commits, which I do not want to push upstream.

I want a faster, more automatic method of squashing the commits that have been auto-generated into the commits that have not. When my log looks something like:

```
<<sha1>> (HEAD -> feature/in-development) Complete feature
<<sha2>> AUTO_COMMIT
<<sha3>> Add function foo()
<<sha4>> AUTO_COMMIT
<<sha5>> AUTO_COMMIT
<<sha6>> Remove function bar()
```

and I'd like to squash every commit with the `AUTO_COMMIT` message, to achieve:

```
<<sha-1>> (HEAD -> feature/in-development) Complete feature
<<sha-2>> Add function foo()
<<sha-3>> Remove function bar()
```

There are variable amounts (1-20 or so) of the `AUTO_COMMIT` commits between 'real' commits.

I've been doing this via manual rebasing. `git rebase --autosquash` looks like it's almost what I want, but my automatically-generated commit messages don't contain the required `...`.

Is there a faster way to squash the auto-commits, or am I stuck with manual-rebasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git rebase -i` command brings up your editor to edit the various `pick` commands.  OK, you already know this and it's no big deal, but not a useful *answer* to your question either, right?  Well, that's the trick: it *is* actually useful.

The way it's useful is that the editor that `git rebase -i` opens on the `pick` commands is set *separately* from all the other editor settings for Git.  Specifically, Git uses `sequence.editor` or `$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` (preferring the latter if it's set, the former otherwise).  It simply runs whatever command this is set to, on the file full of `pick` commands.  (If neither of those is set, Git falls back to the usual `$GIT_EDITOR` / `core.editor` / built-in-default, probably-`vim` editor.)

Therefore, you can write your own script, in any language you prefer, and put this in `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` or `sequence.editor`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
"""
python script to automate replacing `pick <<hash>> AUTO_COMMIT`
with `fixup ...`
"""
```

or:

```
#! /bin/sh
# shell script to automate replacing ...
```

Now, you *do* have to write your program to do this.  It just has to open the file whose name is the parameter to the program, though, replace `pick` with `fixup` or `squash` or whatever you'd like when appropriate, and write that back to the file and exit.

Then, run:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=that_script git rebase -i ...
```

and instead of running `vim` or whatever your editor is on the `pick` commands, it runs your script, which replaces the right ones and off it goes.  If you've chosen "squash" or "edit" for any replacements, that's not part of the "sequence editor" action, so that uses the regular Git editor and still runs `vim` or whatever.

Make yourself a little alias or script to run rebase this way, and you're all set.

Comment: Huh, that's awesome! Thanks!